# Resolution to prevent fingerprinting 1 pixel off?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, fingerprinting, panopticlick

Tor Browser is using letterboxing to prevent [fingerprinting by screen size](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/maximized-torbrowser-window/).

Now, I have done a test on [Cover Your Tracks website from EFF](https://coveryourtracks.eff.org) and the results show a unique fingerprint and the reason for that is a Window Size of `1099x999`. Shouldn't it be `1100x1000` instead?

Edit: My OS **did not** do the window resize "to fit on screen", and even if it did, the letterboxing should put black borders on the sides so websites can not see the screen size.

Edit 2: It is issue [40081](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40081), i am using a high dpi screen. Thank you Peter Gerber for answering!

[image: Screen size fingerprint result]

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is obvious: your OS **did** the window resize "to fit on screen"

Comment: @Alexay how did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: The OS'es do use a GUI managers to display every graphical application content, so unless you'll set the size of the window's viewport at the moment of API call and force it to be preserved - it's a normal GUI behavior to auto-resize windows: Gnome, KDE, etc... From version to version it used to change a bit, so - to drop this specifics it was a wise move to set the explicit and immutable window size, so any browser's component - including add-ons - will be sandboxed for sure

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin perhaps we could add the comment above into the answer if that is good with you?

Comment: @Swangie the answer here can't be any longer because this is just it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct, it should be some nicely round number.

Sadly, there are still some bugs in the implementation. The ones I've observed myself are:

- high-DPI screens can be at fault ([issue 40081](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40081))
- zooming ([issue 32253](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/32253))

I could not find any bugs indicating that fitting a window to the screen could cause this, as suggested by Alexey. If that is what you observe, please [report it as bug](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues).